# how to populate the other schema in my schema and querying for whole object and individual childs?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

am entirely new to Node and Mongo. and am learning from my own.
I have two schemas.1. Tower, 2.Flats

Tower schema

```
var TowerSchema = new Schema({
name:String,
total_unit:Number,
sold_unit:Number,
flats:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:"Sample"}],
createdAt: { type: Date, 'default': Date.now }
});
```

Flat schema

```
var FlatSchema= new Schema({
id: Number,
title:String
})
```

i am saving flats and towers individually. but how to insert flats in towers.

code to save flats

```
router.post('/addSampleData', function(req, res) {
var rsData = fs.readFile('./data/sample_test.json', 'UTF-8', function(err, data) {
    console.log('postdata '+data);
    var parseData = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log('sampleData '+data);
    inserFlat(parseData, res);
})
})
```

code to save tower:

```
router.post('/addTower', function(req, res) {
var fsRead = fs.readFile('./data/tower_sample.json', 'UTF-8', function(err, data){
    console.log('postdata '+data);
    var parseData = JSON.parse(data);
    var sampleJson = fs.readFile('./data/sample_test.json', 
        'UTF-8', function(err1, data1) {
            console.log('sampleData '+data1);
            var sampleData = JSON.parse(data1);
            insertData(parseData, res, sampleData);
        });
})

});
```

you can find that am saving flats(getting flat json from disk) correctly, but while saving towers am doing wrong(getting tower json and flat json).

Please help me how to save this.
and i need to populate the flats in a tower

code to populate:

```
router.get('/flats', function(req, res) {
TowerModel.find().populate('flats').exec(function(err, flats) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('err: '+err)
        res.send({'msg ' : err})
    } else {
        console.log('flats: '+flats)
        res.json(
            {'msg ':flats}
            )
    }

  })
})
```

Please help me here..

Comment: Is the any reason for flats to exists outside of towers?

Comment: towers have flats But flat may or may not exists in Tower.

Comment: Does not make much sense to me. Assuming you really need it stored this way, you probably need to explain why you are not happy with your approach, i.e. expected behaviour and actual results.

Comment: am ok with my saving logic, what am thinking is...while saving tower from json file, am also reading flat json file. Is that correct?or should i fetch flat data from flat collection?

Comment: You are missing crucial information in your question - code for inserting the data, how is `insertData()` function implemented?

Comment: Hmm, if you happy with what it does, it is correct. When you insert new flat, you need to pass the json. When you add existing flat, you need to fetch it from db.